# What's the fastest grand slam tennis singles won

Tags: trivia, tennis, atp, wta, grand-slam

I'd like to know what's the fastest total time of all the matches played by any male and female tennis grand slam champion for the entirety of a single tournament. In other words, what's the shortest duration of play time spent by any male and female grand slam champion over the course of all their matches? To make things even, each champion must have played all 7 matches of the major tournament.

Please provide the champion's name, the year and the tournament of the happening, as well as the time taken to win the major.

Comment: Downvote. _This question does not show any research effort_.

Comment: I doubt the data to support such a question is easily found, and even then, I doubt it has been compiled and sorted in such a way to show the shortest duration of play by a major champion. This just isn't a very important statistic to keep a record of across all time. It's usually only mentioned by broadcasters during the later rounds of the tournament and is likely considered disposable data. Good luck in your search.

Comment: @fedorqui I disagree. As jamauss mentioned such data is not easily found. I'm not talking about the number of games played to win the championship, but the total time taken. Let me know why you think the question doesn't show enough research effort. Your comment also implies that the data should be found somewhat easily doing some research, so I'm interested to see some sources.

Comment: I literally spent years developing a fantasy tennis game a few years ago and have devoted hundreds of hours to scouring the internet for good sources of thorough tennis match data. I think I know what I'm talking about when it comes to what kind of tennis match data is easily found or not.

Comment: Yes, the question is clear but does not show any research effort. If you tried and could not find any, say so! Otherwise this looks like a "make my homework, please" :) https://github.com/JeffSackmann/tennis_atp has the info about duration of the matches on some years and tournaments.

Comment: @fedorqui thumbs up for the link. The whole point of this site is to post questions which the answers cannot be found within a reasonable amount of time. So it's implicitly implied that the OP of any decent question couldn't find the answer. That's why I don't see why any user should say they couldn't find the answer to the question no matter how long they spent looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

For male players (only champions that played 7 full matches (no retirements or walkovers) are considered). data is by [Jeff Sackmann](https://github.com/JeffSackmann/tennis_atp), but it's not entirely complete. Time (last column) is in minutes.

```
tourney_date,tourney_name,winner_name,fulltime
2006-06-26,Wimbledon,Roger Federer,729
2003-06-23,Wimbledon,Roger Federer,745
1996-06-24,Wimbledon,Richard Krajicek,748
2004-06-21,Wimbledon,Roger Federer,753
2004-01-19,Australian Open,Roger Federer,780
1996-05-27,Roland Garros,Yevgeny Kafelnikov,786
2007-01-15,Australian Open,Roger Federer,799
1997-06-23,Wimbledon,Pete Sampras,804
1998-06-22,Wimbledon,Pete Sampras,820
2005-06-20,Wimbledon,Roger Federer,822
```